# Rails new project is not being well generated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, windows-7-x64

I'm new to Ruby and RoR, and following the first steps of the RoR guide, I got a problem. As they say [in the docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html), I tried to install RoR and create a new project.

Firstly, running `gem install rails`, seemed to me that was a problem with the gem `railties`. I ran again `gem install rails` and everything seemed to be fine.

But, when I tried to generate the project running `rails new my_project` an error appeared during the `run bundle install` internal command:

```
      ...blablabla
      create  vendor/assets/stylesheets
      create  vendor/assets/stylesheets/.keep
         run  bundle install
C:/Program Files/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/g
enerators/app_base.rb:331:in ``': No such file or directory - ""C:/Program Files
/Ruby200-x64/bin/ruby.exe"" "C:/Program Files/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/ge
ms/bundler-1.6.2/bin/bundle" install (Errno::ENOENT)
        from C:/Program Files/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.
0/lib/rails/generators/app_base.rb:331:in `block in bundle_command'
        from C:/Program Files/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.2
/lib/bundler.rb:235:in `block in with_clean_env'
        from C:/Program Files/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.2
/lib/bundler.rb:222:in `with_original_env'
        from C:/Program Files/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.2
/lib/bundler.rb:228:in `with_clean_env'
        from C:/Program Files/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.
0/lib/rails/generators/app_base.rb:330:in `bundle_command'
        from C:/Program Files/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.
0/lib/rails/generators/app_base.rb:345:in `run_bundle'
        from (eval):1:in `run_bundle'
        from C:/Program Files/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/l
ib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        from C:/Program Files/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/l
ib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
        from C:/Program Files/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/l
ib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `block in invoke_all'
        from C:/Program Files/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/l
ib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `each'
        from C:/Program Files/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/l
ib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `map'
        from C:/Program Files/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/l
ib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `invoke_all'
        from C:/Program Files/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/l
ib/thor/group.rb:232:in `dispatch'
        from C:/Program Files/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/l
ib/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
        from C:/Program Files/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.
0/lib/rails/commands/application.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Program Files/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kerne
l_require.rb:53:in `require'
        from C:/Program Files/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kerne
l_require.rb:53:in `require'
        from C:/Program Files/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.
0/lib/rails/cli.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Program Files/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kerne
l_require.rb:53:in `require'
        from C:/Program Files/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kerne
l_require.rb:53:in `require'
        from C:/Program Files/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.
0/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Program Files/Ruby200-x64/bin/rails:23:in `load'
        from C:/Program Files/Ruby200-x64/bin/rails:23:in `<main>'
```

I have already deleted the `rails` and `railties` gems and re-installed them, but nothing changes. Any idea?

Versions:

`ruby -v`
ruby 2.0.0p353 (2013-11-22) [x64-mingw32]

`rails -v`
Rails 4.1.0

I'm running on **Windows 7 (x64)**

Comment: You don't need to put "solved" in your title and question. We know it's been solved when you select an answer. If the solution wasn't one submitted by an answerer, then create an answer, tell us what worked and show the specifics for people looking for the same question in the future. Then select your solution as the answer. Don't put the solution in your question, because that's not where it belongs.

Comment: You're right, I had no time to make a proper answer. I''m doing it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a easy solution. I installed Ruby 1.9.3 and everything goes fine now:

`ruby -v`
ruby 1.9.3p545 (2014-02-24) [i386-mingw32]

Answer (score 0):

Try install Ruby under its default directory C:\Ruby200 or C:\Ruby200-x64.

Comment: I'll try and send you feedback. Thanks.

Answer (score -3):

first use the command

```
rails new yourProjectName
```

then run the command

```
rails s
```

to create your server

Comment: I did it, but it's broken during the first command: `rails new project_name`, and also the server doesn't start if I try to turn it on, it throws another error related to the `railties gem`.